# AWS RDS auto backup/snapshot notification

Tags: amazon-web-services

I know there's an automated backup/snapshot in AWS RDS. Do we get notified if it fails? or does it ever fail? SLA says should be 100%  success but it bugs me really if it comes a time it fails and we don't have backups on our own.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to RDS events by subscribing to it. You can find the feature at bottom left in RDS console with name `Event subscriptions` & create new subscriptions so that you get notified on important RDS events.

Currently, I have subscribed to below event set categories -

**Event categories -**

```
availability
configuration change
deletion
failover
recovery
restoration
low storage
failure
```

Ref - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-rds-event-subscription/

Comment: Thanks vivek, but when I reviewed the events related to snapshots it, It doesn't have an event for snapshot failures. Only for created ones. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html

Comment: Ahh.. yes, you are right. There is an event for automated snapshot created but not for any failures. Subscribing to "creation" for DB snapshots might resolve issue temporarily but not a permanent solution. It will notify that a snapshot has been successfully created.